# Core Media plug-in identifier

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, core-media

I have created a CMIO (CoreMediaIO) plug-in for OS X that can access media hardware (in my case a virtual camera) using as the basis [the Apple's example with SDK](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html). Everything works perfectly but now before releasing I came across the problem of getting the unique media plug-in identifier:

[image]

There is not really much the documentation for CoreMedia.framework in general, and I'm curious is there a way to get this unique plug-in identifier in some shared database or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I used TSIs and got the next response from Apple:

> As long as you’re properly generating the
>   UUID, nothing else is required to ensure uniqueness.  The generation process
>   itself guarantees uniqueness.  As for generating the UUID, the command line
>   tool “uuidgen” can take care of that:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/uuidgen.1.html